# Algorithm/Code for detecting colours in a picture

Tags: html, colors, pictures, algorithm

Is it possible to have code that can automatically detect the colours in a picture? If so what is this technology?

Thanks,

Comment: What does it mean to 'detect colors'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be done. For simple uses, a simple python program is sufficient. Using the imaging library:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("image.png")
data = im.getdata()
```

You can now access color data for each pixel of the image in the `data` variable. For more complex needs, there is a lot more that can be done. For example, see a [blog post on finding dominant colors in images](http://charlesleifer.com/blog/using-python-and-k-means-to-find-the-dominant-colors-in-images/).

Comment: That seems like what I'm looking for, many thanks!